# Laravel factory/seeder pivot table

Tags: php, factory, laravel-5.3

I've 3 tables in my Laravel app:

```
Forum
   id
   name
   etc
Topic
   id
   name
   etc
Forum_topic
   forum_id
   topic_id
```

A `Topic` belongsToMany forums.
A `Forum` belongsToMany topics.

Now I'm trying to make a seeder for that. I already made 2 factories for `forum` and `topic`and they work. Now I'm trying to couple them like this in my `DatabaseSeeder.php`:

```
factory(App\Square\Topics\Topic::class,1)->create()->each(function($topic) {
    $topic->forum()->save(factory(App\Square\Forums\Forum::class)->make());
});;
```

My relation in `Topic` model:

```
public function forum()
{
   $this->belongsToMany(Forum::class);
}
```

But I get the error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Call to a member function save() on null
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/seeding#using-model-factories

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try ->create(factory(App\Square\Forums\Forum::class)->make())